# CreateServiceHost method is protected while MSDN says it's public

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Reading an [MSDN tutorial on Extending Hosting Using ServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702697%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), there is an example of overriding a `CreateServiceHost` function:

```
public class DerivedFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
   public override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost( Type t, Uri[] baseAddresses )
   {
      return new DerivedHost( t, baseAddresses )
   }
}
```

However, when we look at the actual definition of the class, the [`CreateServiceHost` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is `protected`:

```
protected virtual ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(
    Type serviceType,
    Uri[] baseAddresses
)
```

My question is, what should I override? Is MSDN example wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `protected` keyword just means that it's only accessible from within the class or subclasses of that class.  If you want to inherit from `ServiceHostFactory`, you shouldn't have a problem.  You can still override `CreateServiceHost`.

Comment: But I can't call it from outside of it. What's the point of overriding it?

Comment: The obvious answer is, "Because you want it to do something other than what the default implementation does".  Sometimes you might want to change something about the internals of how a class accomplishes something.  Overriding a protected method lets you do that.  If you actually have a need to call that method from outside (rather than calling whatever public method on the class uses the protected method to do something) you can always implement a public method on your derived class that calls the protected method.

Comment: It seems like we override the `CreateServiceHost(String blha...)` method instead, ignore the string (since we alreayd know what service we want to create), and off we go. So yeah, I think it's just a stupid api decision on part of WCF team to make that method protected (or at least their decision not to document their decision!). But oh well...